# IE Browser truncating request

Tags: asp.net, ajax, internet-explorer

I tried sending a Ajax request with 20 kb of data..
I am using Internet explorer to do a ajax post call, I found ajax call is sending 20 kb of data correctly, however the same data is not coming in the asp code, when i try to get the data using Request.Form("ItemIDs").

```
var strURL="/logix/folder-feeds.aspx?Action=TransferOffers"; 
         $.ajax({ 
         type:"POST", 
         url: strURL, 
         data : { 
         content : 'application/json', 
         sFolder: sourceFolder, 
         dFolder : destinationFolder, 
         FromOfferList : false, 
         ItemIDs : JSON.stringify(selectedItems), 
         ActionItem : actionele.value 
         }, 
         //traditional:true, 
         success: function (data) { 
         updatepage(data.trim()) 
}});
```

I am able to get the 20 kb of data when i did ajax post using Mozilla Firefox.

I believe IE is chopping the request. 
Is there any setting, i need to do to fix this?